# Prove by Contraposition: $~\forall ~r~ \in ~\mathbb Q~$, $~s~ \in ~\mathbb R~$, if $~s~$ is irrational then $~r + \frac{1}{s}~$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic

**Need help proving that:** $~\forall ~r~ \in ~\mathbb Q~$, $~s~ \in ~\mathbb R~$,  if $~s~$ is irrational then $~r + \frac{1}{s}~$ is irrational

**The contrapositive is:** $~\forall ~r~ \in \mathbb Q~$, $~s~ \in \mathbb R~$,  if $~r + \frac{1}{s}~$ is rational then $~s~$ is rational

I don't seem to be getting anywhere with it.

Comment: Can you write the contrapositive version of your statement?

Comment: Assume r/s is rational and take it from there.

Comment: Generalizing Eric Towers' advice, it is almost always beneficial to rephrase theorems in a more positive manner. (Particularly, to make it so that the premises are state positively.)

Comment: To move to the next step, theorems are based on definitions. What is the definition of rational? What does it mean to say $r$, $s$, and $r/s$ are rational?

Comment: So should I take do something like r/s = a/b where a, b are nonzero? @DerekElkins

Comment: Given that $r$ and $r/s$ are rational, consider $r/(r/s)$...

Comment: Incidentally, the statement is false for $r=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHock1 a rational number $n$ can be defined as $n=\frac{a}{b}, b\neq 0$.  Moreover, proofs often rely on defining $n$ as a _non-reducible_ rational number (i.e. $\gcd(a,b)=1$).

Comment: Please do not edit a question to change it into another question altogether. If you have a new question, ask a new question (you can delete the old one if you feel it is no longer relevant).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for some choice of $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $r + \frac{1}{s} = \frac{p}{q}$, hence 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{s} = \frac{p}{q} - r
\end{align}
Verify that the sum of two rational numbers is also a rational number itself. Then, $\frac{1}{s}$ is rational, so $s$ is rational. (The nonzero rational number $a/b$ has multiplicative inverse $b/a$.)

REMARK: It is not appropriate when trying to prove the statement to assume $r/s$ is rational. Why? Put $r/s = t$. Then, $r/t = s$. See then that $s$ is rational if and only if $r/s$ is rational, thus assuming $r/s$ is rational is like assuming that we already have the desired result.

If $r = 0$, the statement says that the multiplicative inverse of a rational number is also rational.

Comment: Remark about your remark: the question was modified after comments were made, rendering them irrelevant.

Comment: @fkraiem gotcha, that explains a bunch actually

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb Q$ is closed under $+,-, \times,$ and reciprocals. "Closed under" means that if $r,r'\in \Bbb Q$ then $r'+r,\,r'-r,\,rr' \in \Bbb Q$ and if $0\ne x\in \Bbb Q$ then $x^{-1}\in \Bbb Q.$

Suppose $r\in \Bbb Q$ and $s\not \in \Bbb Q$ and  $r+\frac {1}{s}\in \Bbb Q.$

Let $r'=r+\frac {1}{s}.$   Since $r,r'\in \Bbb Q$ we have

$$r+\frac {1}{s}=r'\implies \frac {1}{s}=r'-r\in \Bbb Q$$ $$\implies \frac {1}{s}\in \Bbb Q$$ $$\implies 0\ne\frac {1}{s}\in \Bbb Q \quad\text {(because no $\frac {1}{s}$ can be $0$)}$$ $$\implies s=\left(\frac {1}{s}\right)^{-1}\in \Bbb Q$$ contrary to the assumption that $s\not \in \Bbb Q.$

Answer (score 0):

If $r+\frac{1}{s}=r'$ would be rational, then $\frac{1}{s}=r'-r$ would be rational and so $s= \frac{1}{r'-r}$ would be rational. Contradiction.

Note that the rational numbers form a field and so closed under addition and multiplication.
Here if $r,r'$ are rational, then $r'-r = r'+(-r)$ and $\frac{1}{r} = r^{-1}$ are rational.